# index.php rewriting headers, best practice?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an index.php which handles all of my redirects for my newly designed site. My old site uses ugly url formatting, eg: /playgame.php?gameid=123. My htaccess handles the internal rewrites and my index.php handles all the old otherwise broken links. The new url for the same example stated earlier would be /games/bunny-invasion-2, and if entered it is rewritten as such thanks to index.php

In index.php I've also got all my homepage html. I've made sure to call exit() after calling header() in the php, so this is not a problem.
For correctly formatted urls, eg /games/????, it calls include("pages/games.php") between the consistent and never-changing header and footer.

It all works fine, but I'm not sure if it's the best method efficiency wise.
The homepage HTML never gets run in the case of a redirect because exit is called before it can be processed ... at least I think that's the case? Either way the html adds to the download size slightly.

Would it be better practice to isolate all my header rewrite functionality in a simpler more compact index.php? When using a single index.php to handle all urls is this the norm? Or is this completely negligible considering my html is less than 5kb?

Comment: `exit` means your script stops working right there and then, so if all your HTLM code comes only after that it does of course __not__ “add to the download size.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exit()` calls a stop to the script. From that perspective, your HTML does not get processed further, and so it does not add to the download size for the user.

Efficiency-wise I'd say you're doing well. You're including what needs to be included when and if it needs to be included, and have only the basic logics to support that. I see no quicker way neither code-wise nor download-wise to do this.